# Balance between Number of Threads and Web Requests

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, httpwebrequest

I have a program that executes multiple threads. Each thread simply executes a HTTPWebRequest and then screen scrapes the page looking for some text. I am a race against other users to find this text. I could execute 1000000 threads, all looking for the same thing.

My thought on that is that would put a lot of work on my processor and would actually cause the requests to execute slower. How can I find a balance between the number of threads to execute and the performance of the web requests. Basically what I want to do is find the optimal number of threads to spawn off so that the amount of data they pull down is greatest.

The application is using .NET4 and written in C#.

Comment: Each processor/core can really only do one thing at a time, so 1000000 - the number of cores on your PC would lay idle for a large portion of their life anyway.

Comment: Playing for Arsenal is like 'laying idle for a large portion of your life'.

Comment: @MartinJames - says who a spuds fan? :P

Comment: Executing 1000000 threads is a really bad idea unless you have a pretty awesome PC from the future.

Comment: @RobinVanPersi - Spuds fan?  Not me, but I note that St. Totteringham's day is late this year...

Comment: @BrianRasmussen - you get that one to debug :)

Comment: Also each thread takes 1mb of memory space so to run 1000000 concurrent threads you'll need a 64-bit machine with 1TB of ram!

Answer (score 1):

You are right to assume that 1000000 threads will put undue pressure on your CPU. The work that your CPU would have to do to manage and switch between that many threads would probably cause your system to be very slow indeed.

Obviously you are not serious about 1000000 threads, but it demonstrates that you cannot simply throw more threads at the problem. You dont really want to write your own load balancer - that will not be easy and will not perform as well as the classes that come with the base class library. Have a look at using ThreadPool threads - the CLR will manage them for you. You can also look at the Parallel Task Library that is new in .NET 4.0 (since you mention that is what you are using).

ALso check out this great article about multi-threading:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 1):

C# has a ThreadPool.  Submit your web-scraping tasks to the pool.  You can tweak the number of threads in the pool to tune your app - you will probably need to increase it well above the default for best performance with such a requirement as yours.

Huge numbers of threads are wasteful, as posted by @M Babcock.

I'm not sure if the number of threads in a C# ThreadPool can be changed at run-time, (I see no reason why not, but M$...).  If it is tweakable during the run, tuning will be even easier!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `Parallel.Foreach` to manage your threads properly...

Comment: That's a pretty strong statement considering there are about a dozen other ways to handle thread management in .NET.

Comment: @M.Babcock - its a solution to the problem its not considered as an ultimate solution, if you have a better idea please share... :)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking performance question and not providing any estimates on your actual requirements... so let me try doing it for you.

How much data can you pull in - assuming awesome network and regular network card - 100Mb/s at max, probably less than 10Mb/sec. This give about less than 10000 requests per second (assuming ~10K requests/response pairs).

Can one thread handle that much data - searching through 100Mb a second should not be a problem even for single thread. Super easy to prototype/measure.

How many threads I need to read data - likely 1 - starting asynchronous request is fast, reading response OR posting response in a queue for processing is fast for 10000 items a second.

So my estimates - 1 thread for simple code, (1 + one thread per core) if you have more cores and willing to run processing in parallel.